# How to update without altering the structure of table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a structure like as below.

```
create table test_table (id INT NOT NUll AUTO_INCREMENT
                         , name varchar(100),
                         primary key (id))ENGINE=INNODB
Select * from test_table;
id   name
1    a
2    b
3    c
```

Now I want to increment the id by a number lets say 2
So the final results should be

```
Select * from test_table;
id   name
3    a
4    b
5    c
```

The way I can do it is, first remove the PK and auto increment and then 
update the table:

```
update test_table set id=id+2;
```

The other way is to make a temp table with out PK and auto increment and then
   extract the result to the main table.

Is there any other way to do this without destroying the table structure ?
   I am using MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you need to remove the PK first to allow (temporary) duplicate `id`'s during the course of the update.
To avoid duplicates, you must perform an ordered update:

```
UPDATE test_table SET id = id + 2 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This will update records with largest value of `id` first, hence avoiding collision.

Obviously, if you want to decrement the values of `id`, then use "`ORDER BY id ASC`".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to update the tables in SQL :- Its generic

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1=value, column2=value2,WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Please follow the link for more information

[Update Query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Thanks,
Pavan